# How to count total quantity in a list with multiple occurences

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I'm quite new to bash and its syntax, therefore I would like to know how to sort a list to get the total number for an inventory of our hard drives.

Example is below. We have many servers and many hard drives from different vendors and models.

How would you count them together based on the numbers and not the occurrence of their name.

```
ST8000NC0002: 8
ST900MM0168: 1
ST900MM0168: 1
ST9300603SS: 3
ST9300605SS: 4
ST9500620SS: 3
WD1003FBYX: 7
WD1500HLFS: 4
WD9001BKHG: 3
WD9001BKHG: 3
WD9001BKHG: 4
WD9001BKHG: 4
```

---

Desired output:

```
ST8000NC0002: 8 
ST900MM0168: 2 
ST9300603SS: 3 
ST9300605SS: 4 
ST9500620SS: 3 
WD1003FBYX: 7 
WD1500HLFS: 4 
WD9001BKHG: 14
```

Comment: Thanks jesse_b. Will be more precise in future to avoid misinterpretations.

Comment: `awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' file | sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is made for this.  Populate an array (`data`) indexed by the first field (`$1`), accumulating values from the second field (`$2`).  Once the array is populated, output the data using a simple `for` loop.  Pipe the output through `sort` for convenience.

```
awk '{data[$1]+=$2} END { for( d in data ) { print d, data[d] } }' input | sort
ST8000NC0002: 8
ST900MM0168: 2
ST9300603SS: 3
ST9300605SS: 4
ST9500620SS: 3
WD1003FBYX: 7
WD1500HLFS: 4
WD9001BKHG: 14
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the delayed answer. I've tested your solution and tried to understand it on other examples, took a time to figure out how awk works but i think it helped me to get a better understanding of how to handle my inventory. It works like intended. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `datamash`:

```
datamash -W -g 1 sum 2 < file
```

- `-W` use whitspace (spaces/tabs) as field delimiter (instead of tabs)
- `-g 1` group on the first field
- `sum 2` sum values on the second field (per group)

Output:

```
ST8000NC0002:   8
ST900MM0168:    2
ST9300603SS:    3
ST9300605SS:    4
ST9500620SS:    3
WD1003FBYX:     7
WD1500HLFS:     4
WD9001BKHG:     14
```

This works fine since your input is already sorted on the first field. For unsorted input, add option `-s` to sort the input before grouping.